# extract a value from the output of a script and store in a variable linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a command that if I execute, it gives me below output:

```
[abctt]$ /abc/prr/test.sh config -get center.id
Connecting to the service endpoint at http://localhost:8003

POY Properties:
UU001
```

Now I want to extract "UU001" value and store in a variable and then print that variable value. So I tried something like below but it gives me error:

```
[abctt]$ id=`/abc/prr/test.sh config -get center.id | tail -2`;echo $id
id=UU001: Command not found.
id: Undefined variable.
```

What is wrong I am doing here?

Comment: It looks like your first problem is that you're using `csh` not `bash`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct inside of a script.

Try this:

```
export id=`/abc/prr/test.sh config -get center.id | tail -2`;echo $id
```

If you are using csh,

```
set id=`/abc/prr/test.sh config -get center.id | tail -2`;echo $id
```